# Threading in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, python-multithreading

I write **Python 3** code, in which I have 2 functions. The first function insertBlock() inserts data in **MongoDB** collection 1, the second function insertTransactionData() takes data from collection 1 and inserts it into collection 2. Data is in very large amount so I use threading to increase performance. But when I use threading it is taking more time to insert data than without threading. I am so confused that exactly how threading will work in my code and how to increase performance? Here is the main function :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
   t1 = threading.Thread(target=insertBlock())  
   t1.start()  
   t2 = threading.Thread(target=insertTransactionData())  
   t2.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

From the python documentation for [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

So the correct usage is

```
threading.Thread(target=insertBlock)
```

(without the `()` after `insertBlock`), because otherwise `insertBlock` is called, executed normally (blocking the main thread) and `target` is set to it's return value `None`. This causes `t1.start()` not to do anything and you don't get any performance improvement.

**Warning:**
Be aware that multithreading gives you no guarantee on what the order of execution in different threads will be. You can not rely on the data that `insertBlock` has inserted into the database inside the `insertTransactionData` function, because at the time `insertTransactionData` uses this data, you can not be sure that it was already inserted. So, maybe multithreading does not work at all for this code or you need to restructure your code and only parallelize those parts that do not depend on each other.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But if I do like this I am getting the error:    Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "Test06.py", line 97, in insertTransactionData
for tx in blockResult["transactions"]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @VarshaKhandre This is a problem in `insertTransactionData` (`blockResult` is `None`) and you didn't include that part of the code. Please read my edit about the problems of multithreading and inform yourself about parallelization (this is your goal here). If you still need help for that problem, please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by merging these two functionalities into one new function 
`insertBlockAndTransaction(startrange,endrange)`. As these two functionalities depend on each other so what I did is I insert transaction information immediately below where block information is inserted (block number was common and needed for both functionalities).Then did multithreading by creating 10 threads for single function:

```
for i in range(10):
   print('thread:',i)
   t1 = threading.Thread(target=insertBlockAndTransaction,args(5000000+i*10000,5000000+(i+1)*10000))
   t1.start()
```

It helps me to deal with increasing execution time for more than 1lakh data.